# How to POST a Laravel form with cURL from CLI?

Tags: laravel, http, curl, post, laravel-5

I have a laravel application with a form, where upon a `GET` request (`example.my.lan/form`) of the formular the user receives a `*_session` cookie and a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. Now I'm trying to call the controller (`example.my.lan/form/confirmation`) via `POST` on the command line with `cURL`:

```
curl -vvv -k -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--cookie "my_form_session=a...z" \
--cookie "XSRF-TOKEN=a...z" https://example.my.lan/form/confirmation

curl -vvv -k -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "my_form_session=a...z" \
-H "XSRF-TOKEN=a...z" https://example.my.lan/form/confirmation

curl -vvv -k -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "my_form_session: a...z" \
-H "XSRF-TOKEN: a...z" https://example.my.lan/form/confirmation
```

From my browser everything works as expected. But if I call the controller on the CLI using `cURL`, the laravel app is always responding with a `419` (The page has expired). I know this is some cookie related issue, but still can't figure ou how to solve it - maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: you will need to send a valid session cookie along with a corresponding csrf token

Comment: @apokryfos yes I do that, I grabbed the cookie from a previous `cURL` call. You certainly mean, that this one is not valid anymore, do you? In that case, how could I grab a "fresh" cookie from CLI?

Comment: The main thing is to make sure the CSRF token corresponds to the same session which the cookie refers to. You also need to pass it in the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header. (The XSRF-TOKEN is the cookie name that would hold the encrypted token). If you want to send the token from the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie that needs to go in header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`

Comment: @apokryfos you helped me, thanks! If you like, post it as an answer, I want to give you some points :)

Comment: @apokryfos sorry to disturb you again, but now I get "The payload is invalid." - do you have any idea? I'm passing the content of `XSRF-TOKEN` as `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as a header like you suggested.

Comment: Because that's encrypted and probably uses an IV I think you need to get it every time before sending it. Not exactly sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So roughly speaking here's what needs to happen:

You need to perform an initial request to get a valid session cookie (which is essentially an encrypted session id) and along with that you also need to somehow obtain a valid CSRF token.

To get the token you have two options.

1. Visit a page which has a form which includes it via `@csrf`
2. Grab the cookie called `XSRF-TOKEN` which contains the encrypted csrf token

When you send the request you need to be sure you send the correct session cookie e.g. `--cookie "my_form_session=a...z"`.

If you got the token from the `@csrf` field then you either send the header `X-CSRF-TOKEN` or as an additional form field `_token=csrftoken`

If you got the token from the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie, which contains an encrypted CSRF token, this needs to go in the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` field.

By convention, all non-standard HTTP headers should be prefixed with `X-` (indicating an extension to the protocol) which is why those headers start with `X-`